# Windows 10, Ubuntu, Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox, windows-10-upgrade

I have Windows XP running in a virtual box. I'm trying to upgrade that to Windows 10. I have the .iso file on the computer and also burned onto a CD. I launched virtualbox and it asked if I want to load from CD and I said yes. It seemed to start, but then froze up.

How can I upgrade without wiping the old XP virtual box session and putting the new one on? If I wipe it then I think I will have to install all the software and files so trying to just upgrade and everything stay the way it is.
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Windows XP itself will not upgrade to Windows 10.

Upgrading your computer from Win7 or Win8 to Win10 can be done in such a way that it will leave all your files intact, including all you have done in Virtualbox.

So your problem is not going to be with either XP nor Virtualbox.  It will be with the Windows 10 upgrade.

Comment: You need to find the shortest upgrade path from Win XP to Win 10. Maybe XP -> Vista ->8 ->10, or something else, then get licensed copies of everything in that path, and upgrade from one to the next until you get to Win10. That said, saving your data files, and starting over with a Win 10 install, and reinstall the software might be faster, and cleaner. Sure to be cheaper!

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  So I'm trying to create a new virtualbox for Win10, but it will not load from the ISO file.  It keeps freezing up.  Any thoughts what I can do?